# Иконка сайта в мета отображается правильная только на localhost. При деплое на vercel иконка заменяется на дефолтную

Tags: nextjs, next.js, metadata, next, favicon

Я пытаюсь изменить иконку веб сайта в мета информации, на localhost она отображается, а после того как залил сайт на Vercel - ставиться дефолтная инконка nextJs.
Я иконку менял размещая файл favicon.ico в папку app, а также заливал иконку в папку public/icons и вписывал вручную - безуспешно

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.